# What Lightbox plugin is this?

Tags: plugins, lightbox

Can anyone tell me what is being used to generate the image on this page?

http://www.iwantoneofthose.com/lego-digital-camera/index.html#productSubmitReviewsAnchor

I assume it's some kind of lightbox plugin?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is jquery based and the "close lightbox" icon is similar to the one used in fancybox.

http://fancybox.net/